# How do I grab the last available value in a row to fill an NaN value

Tags: pandas

I have the following DataFrame -

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'city': ['Monroe', 'Montgomery'], 
        2005: [144, 205], 
        2006: [173,  211], 
        2007: [np.NaN, np.NaN], 
        2008: [np.NaN, 206], 
        2009: [np.NaN, np.NaN], 
        2010: [128, 273]
    }
)
```

For all the NaN values, how do I grab the last available value to return the following -

```
Monroe -     144, 173, 173, 173, 173, 128
Montgomery - 205, 211, 211, 206, 206, 273
```

PS I'm only showing 2 rows, my dataframe has 1111 rows.

Comment: `dfx.ffill(1)` ?

Comment: are your years columns sorted?  if not try `dfx.set_index('city').stack(dropna=False).sort_index().ffill().bfill().unstack()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider this one-liner

```
dfx.T.ffill().T
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
dfx.fillna(method="ffill")
```